Help with derivative command
I am trying to find the Mathematica command for
$$f(k,a,b)=\frac{\partial^k}{\partial {a}^k }\csc\left(ab\pi\right)$$ and here is what typed for the command F[k_,a_,b_]:=D[Csc[a b Pi],{a,k}]. Now I dont know how to obtain, for example, F[2,1/5,1/3]; but this gives an D::ivar error. Any idea? Thank you.

Clear[F]; F[k_, a_, b_] = D[Csc[a b Pi], {a, k}]; F[2, 1/5, 1/3]

Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=ivar+D+%5Bwarning-messages%5D

Another alternative: F[k_, a_, b_] := D[Csc[Hold[a] b Pi], {Hold[a], k}] // ReleaseHold.

@MichaelE2 this is truly nice and simple

Solution
Perhaps you want to evaluate the derivative first and replace the values later.
 Clear[f];
 f[k_, a_, b_] := ReplaceAll[
          D[ Csc[aa bb Pi], {aa, k}]
          , { aa->a, bb->b }
 ]

N[f[2, 1/5, 1/3]]
(* 238.76  *)

Your problem
Otherwise, you are doing
D[Csc[1/5 * 1/3 * Pi],{1/5,2}]

And you can't take the derivative with respect to a number.
cvgmt's comment
If you try to calculate the derivative in general first, without knowing the value of k, you get a complicated expression that depends on K[1], that's why the comment by  @cvgmt doesn't work the way you expect.

Further remarks
Avoid variables starting with uppercase characters, as these are likely to collide with Mathematica reserved symbols.
@MichaelE2 offers a very elegant alternative solution (+1).

Alternative with Derivative instead of D:
f[k_, a_, b_] := Derivative[k][Csc[# b Pi] &][a]

f[1, x, E]
(*
-E \[Pi] Cot[E \[Pi] x] Csc[E \[Pi] x]
*)

f[2, 1/5, 1/3] // ToRadicals // FullSimplify
(*
1/9 Sqrt[
 2 (6020 + 2609 Sqrt[5] + Sqrt[70200975 + 31379430 Sqrt[5]])
 ] \[Pi]^2
*)


This is not an answer for your question only solution for the derivative in general k:
Using:
$$\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } 2 i \exp (-(2 j+1) i a b \pi )=\csc (a b \pi )$$
Then:
$$\frac{\partial ^k\csc (a b \pi )}{\partial a^k}=(2 i)^{1+k} b^k e^{-i a b \pi } (-\pi )^k \Phi \left(e^{-2 i a b \pi },-k,\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
Sum[D[2 I E^(I a b (-1 - 2 j) \[Pi]), {a, k}] // PowerExpand // 
ExpandAll, {j, 0, Infinity}] // PowerExpand

(*(2 I)^(1 + k) b^k E^(-I a b \[Pi]) (-\[Pi])^k LerchPhi[
E^(-2 I a b \[Pi]), -k, 1/2]*)

f[k_, a_, b_] := Derivative[k][Csc[# b Pi] &][a]; f[2, 1/5, 1/3] // N
(*238.76*)

g[k_, a_, b_] := (2 I)^(1 + k) b^k E^(-I a b \[Pi]) (-\[Pi])^
k LerchPhi[E^(-2 I a b \[Pi]), -k, 1/2]; g[2, 1/5, 1/3] // N

(*238.76 + 1.13687*10^-13 I*)


Thank you for the info (+1)
